# What is the best way to called non-static method from static method in java?

Tags: java, static

I know there are a lot of questions about this topic. 
I have two procedures to call arrPrint method.

1st Procedure:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Test test = new Test();
    test.arrPrint(arr);

}

public void arrPrint(int[] arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      System.out.println(arr[i]);

  }
}
```

2nd Procedure :

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };      
    arrPrint(arr);
}

public static void arrPrint(int[] arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Which procedure is best and why?

Comment: Why do you need plenty of ways to call the instance method? To ask which one is better? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods run on instances of a class, so to execute an instance method you need an instance of a class. Therefore, if you want to call an instance method from within a static method, you need some access to an instance, either a global variable or passed as argument. Otherwise, you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

"Instance method" means the method needs to be executed on an instance of the class. The point of objects is that instances can have their own dedicated data, which the instance methods act on, so trying to call an instance method without an object instance doesn't make sense. If you rewrite your example to:

```
public class Test {

    int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.arrPrint();
    }

    public void arrPrint() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

then this becomes a little simpler. The instance of Test has its own data, which the instance method can access and do something with.

Look at JDK classes like String or ArrayList and see how they're designed. They encapsulate data and allow it to be accessed through instance methods.

On the other hand static methods can't see instance data, because they don't belong to an object instance. If an instance method doesn't touch any instance data, some static analysis tools like sonarqube will recommend that the instance method be changed to a static method. Since your method operates on data that is passed in and the object created to call it as an instance method is unnecessary, it's better for it to be a static method.

Answer (score 0):

2nd procedure is used if you want to use the method `arrPrint` in another class.

```
public class A{
    public int[] intArray;

    public A(int[] intArray) {
        this.intArray = intArray;
    }

    public int[] getIntArray() {
        return intArray;
    }        
}


public class Pourtest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    A a = new A(arr);
    arrPrint(a.getIntArray());
}

    public static void arrPrint(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```